# Best type for stochastic matrices — need a source

Tags: c#, java, floating-point, double

I rewrote entire question to make it clear.

I need a type that can hold a [stochastic matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix). I need this to be in Java or C# (Java preffered).

I need a built-in type. It could be a class written by someone but a problem is that in my thesis I need reference to everything so it should come from an article, book, etc...

As in stochastic matrix, all elements in a row need to sum to 1, I need a datatype that will guarantee that. I am aware of the fact that a built-in types can't guarantee that. But is there a type that can guarantee that is we assume that every value calculated is rounded up to e.g. 10 digits?

I also need a reference to a book or article where it is mentioned that this data type can be used for storing stochastic matrices in computer memory.

Is `BigDecimal` from Java or `decimal` from C# suitable?

Comment: What do you mean by the "best" type?

Comment: I don't have a very good understanding of stochastic matrices, but I see a problem right off the bat.  You need more precision than a double can provide.  "a stochastic vector as a vector whose elements consist of nonnegative real numbers which sum to 1" (wikipedia).  What if the elements stored actually add to 0.9999999999999993 or something but when you calculated the elements they added to 1?

Comment: @Corbin: So I need other data type of format...

Comment: Well as Oli said, it depends on best.  With any type of data structure, there's always trade offs.  An N-dimensional array of doubles would likely be the best option in a performance-tight situation.  Higher precision types (non-native types most likely) would be 'better' in situations where absolute precision was non-negotiable.

Comment: Does `BigDecimal` guarantee that a sum will be 1?

Comment: "You know something" - well, that implies that you consciously chose `double` for a particular reason.  What was that reason?

Comment: I chose `double` because I knew that it will sum to 1. In my examples I use values of probabilities 0.1 or 0.4 but not 1.12312e-34. But as you say, in general `double` might not be the best type (in terms of precision). So, I need any other type that will guarantee sum=1 for any value representable by that type.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28double%29 seems to disagree with me that 0.1 can be held in `double`...

Comment: @JanAjan: There is no guarantee that it will sum to 1, even with relatively "simple" values.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, yeah :(. I just learned that ;/

Comment: It's not a PhD thesis. I don't have to do anything novel in it. That is not important... I just need a source of information.

Comment: You could use fixpoint, or rationals

Comment: 1. It is not possible to represent infinitely going on decimals in binary format. So, with some numbers, they will not exactly add up to 1.00000000. 2. You can try fractions, if the numbers you are using are usable, or you have to accept a small offset at the nth decimal (you can control that decimal yourself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no inbuilt type (in either of those languages) that will satisfy the (reasonably arbitrary) requirement that all the rows sum to 1. Of course, it's pretty trivial to write this yourself (and in the case of floating points, using the appropriate error margin ...).

I can't imagine why you need a reference for just saying "the matrix will be stochastic". If you need to clearly specify the type (for some bizarre reason ...) then you'll have to resort to specifying the algorithm that will enforce the integrity you need (which, obviously, is remarkably trivial.)

Comment: I don't need a reference for saying "the matrix will be stochastic". I need a reference to justify my choice of the type I chose.

Comment: No you don't; you just need an argument as to why it's valid. Either you can provide that argument, or you can find someone else who has. But I'd suggest that it is so trivial that you can do it.

Comment: Which would you use? `double`, `deecimal`, `BigDecimal`?

Comment: I'd use c# and `decimal`, because it doesn't suffer the same problems as double. But in some sense it doesn't matter, because you still have to make the same sort of comments about error margins and range of valid probabilities that can be considered (and for *that*, you need a reference, namely from the languages themselves, which you may easily find).

Comment: `BigDecimal` in Java vs `decimal` in C#? Which is better and why?

Comment: Why don't you read the respective documentation and find out for yourself? How do you rate "better"? Only you know that, so clearly I can't tell you.